# Can one work with JavaScript without any tools?

Tags: javascript

To work with javascript, is it necessary to have some of the tools, or can it be done "dry" like that? Does it matter if I include not only BIT, but also Helios, React, or one of the other tools in my environment?
P.S. I'm just a beginner so if the question is imprecise or unclear, please forgive me.

I didn't do anything yet.

Comment: Hi, search for "vanilla javascript" on google and you will find a whole world.

Comment: It's not clear what's being asked. All you **need** is a JS runtime, like NodeJS or a browser. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: You only need a magnetized needle and a steady hand

Comment: The question is quite clear to me – it seems to ask about vanilla JavaScript. I would vote to reopen, but I don't have such rights yet. Also I think this question is *not* opinion-based. The answer is "yes (vanilla JavaScript), but you need a platform (browser or Node.js)".

Comment: And, for a beginner, the question is definitely worded okay (it gives React as an example, which provides enough context to make sense of the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with JavaScript, you don't necessarily need any specific tools, but having a good development environment and using certain tools can greatly enhance your productivity and make your coding experience more enjoyable.

You can start making HTML files, with javascript code inside it, and running it in the browser. Then, given some time, you will learn about the tools and, most important, what problems do they solve. So, it will become natural to use other tools as your learning progresses.

Answer (score 0):

If by tools you mean an IDE, for example, then yes you can write javascipt code using Notepad++ for example, which is an evelved notepad style tool and it is free of charge. The advantage of using "tools" like and IDE for programming, is that they give you a way to run your code, then test, and also check the syntax of what you write. I found these features very important for me when I started coding a few years back.